# Transfering my Clash of Clans progress from Android to Windows

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have logged in with Google play games, and want to know if I can get my progress saved on my new Windows phone.

Comment: Unlikely. You'd most likely be using separate accounts for Google and Microsoft, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Does your Windows COC have the *'Link a device'* option in the settings menu?

If so, on your **old** device, go to **Settings > Devices > Link a device > This is the old device**. You will be issued a code.

On your **new** device, **Settings > Devices > Link a device > This is the new device** and input the code from your old device.

The rest is pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

from this day clash of clans isn't available for windows phone please do a little search before posting any question.